# Find range of one variable for specific values of a different variable

Tags: r

I'm new to r and I cannot seem to find the correct keywords to address my question.

What I am trying to do is find the ranges of a variable for each value of another variable in my dataset.
So for example, my dataset looks like

variable1:
34,45,67,24,60,34

variable2
1,1,2,2,3,3

For each value of variable2, I would like the range of variable1 values. So for the value '1' in variable1, I would get 34-45, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `tapply`

```
tapply(variable1, variable2, FUN = range)
```

If it is from a data.frame

```
with(df1, tapply(variable1, variable2, FUN = range))
#$`1`
#[1] 34 45

#$`2`
#[1] 24 67

#$`3`
#[1] 34 60
```

---

If it is a `data.frame`, then we can use `aggregate` as well if we need a summarised column

```
aggregate(variable1 ~ variable2, df1, 
        FUN = function(x) paste(range(x), collapse="-"))
# variable2 variable1
#1         1     34-45
#2         2     24-67
#3         3     34-60
```

Or if we need to create a new column use `ave`

```
df1$Range <- with(df1, ave(variable1, variable2, FUN = 
             function(x) paste(range(x), collapse="-")))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(variable2) %>%
     mutate(Range = str_c(range(variable1), collapse="-"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   variable2 [3]
#  variable1 variable2 Range
#      <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>
#1        34         1 34-45
#2        45         1 34-45
#3        67         2 24-67
#4        24         2 24-67
#5        60         3 34-60
#6        34         3 34-60
```

If we need a summarised output

```
df1 %>%
      group_by(variable2) %>%
      summarise(Range = str_c(range(variable1), collapse="-"), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  variable2 Range
#      <dbl> <chr>
#1         1 34-45
#2         2 24-67
#3         3 34-60
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(variable1 = c(34, 45, 67, 24, 60, 34), 
       variable2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
```